# Extract multiple values between XML tags

Tags: bash

I have an XML file which is from a Tripadvisor page, and it shows restaurants in a specific area.

I want to extract the 'cuisines' offered from all of the restaurants in the search result. All of the values are stored between `<a>` and `<span>` HTML tags.

For each restaurant, the data is stored between a `<div>` tag, a snippet of the cuisines from one restaurant is shown below:

```
<div class="cuisines">
<span class="item price">££ - £££</span>
<span class="item cuisine" onclick="ta.restaurant_list_tracking.clickNonLinkedCuisine()">Bar</span>
<a class="item cuisine" href="/Restaurants-g1096751-c7-Whittlebury_Northamptonshire_England.html" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('RESTAURANT_DETAILS', 'RESTAURANTS_DETAILS_CUISINE', '', 0, this.href);">British</a>
<span class="item cuisine" onclick="ta.restaurant_list_tracking.clickNonLinkedCuisine()">Pub</span>
<span class="item cuisine" onclick="ta.restaurant_list_tracking.clickNonLinkedCuisine()">Gastropub</span>
<a class="item cuisine" href="/Restaurants-g1096751-zfz10665-Whittlebury_Northamptonshire_England.html" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('RESTAURANT_DETAILS', 'RESTAURANTS_DETAILS_CUISINE', '', 0, this.href);">Vegetarian Friendly</a>
<a class="item cuisine" href="/Restaurants-g1096751-zfz10992-Whittlebury_Northamptonshire_England.html" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('RESTAURANT_DETAILS', 'RESTAURANTS_DETAILS_CUISINE', '', 0, this.href);">Gluten Free Options</a>
</div>
```

How do I go about extracting the cuisines between these `div` tags for each restaurant and then outputting it into a new text file?

The expected output I would want from that snippet of code would be:

```
Bar, British, Pub, Gastropub, Vegetarian Friendly, Gluten Free Options
```

Mind you, there are several `<div>` tags in this XML file, and I want to process through all of them, extracting the results of all the different cuisines into one text file. With each line showing all the cuisines for each `<div>` block.

Thanks!

Comment: Do some research into XML processing tools like [tag:xmlstarlet] or [tag:xmllint], or languages like python or ruby with solid XML parsing libraries.

Comment: Really XML, or HTML? (It matters, because while baseline HTML *looks* like XML, it's not quite compliant, so widely available tools won't accept it).

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45309055/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic bash script (using awk) that does the job, at least for the example you provided:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cat in.xml | awk '
/item cuisine/ {item=gensub(/<[^>]*>/, "", "g"); 
    ans = (ans=="") ? item : ans ", " item;}
END {print ans}' > out.txt
```

The script removes all text inside brackets and retains only the text between them, and only on lines containing "item cuisine".

**However**, note that this is a *very* fragile way of extracting values from an XML file, or, for that matter, any Data Exchange Format (like JSON, YAML etc.), and could stop working for a dozen different reasons (bad XML format, an XML line containing the "item cuisine" term outside of brackets, XML tags not being broken up by newlines, etc.).

One could always extend the above script and cover an increasing number of errors, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel as this has already been done in a much better way. Tools like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) or [xgrep](http://wohlberg.net/public/software/xml/xgrep/) offer much more robust XML parsing, letting you concentrate only on the task at hand instead of the error handling.

If this is anything more than a quick personal hack/experiment, I'd urge you to use one of the already available tools.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into tools made specifically for XML parsing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using XMLStarlet, assuming your content is in `in.xml`:

```
# Generate an array of cuisines
cuisines=( )
while IFS= read -r cuisine; do
  cuisines+=( "$cuisine" )
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -t \
           -m '//div[@class="cuisines"]/*[@class="item cuisine"]' \
           -v . -n \
           <in.xml)

# Transform that into a string with a command and space after each item
printf -v cuisines_str '%s, ' "${cuisines[@]}"

# Remove the trailing ", " from that string on output
echo "${cuisines_str%, }"
```